# R - How to calculate in a new column the difference in seconds between the first and the remaining dates

Tags: r, date

I have the following dates and I want to calculate the difference between the first date and the other dates. e.g. The difference must be date 2- date 1, date 3 - date 1 etc, in seconds and in another column.
Any help is appreciated I am new in R.

```
"2009-06-01 16:00:00 UTC" 
"2009-06-29 16:00:00 UTC" 
"2009-06-29 17:00:00 UTC"
"2009-06-30 16:00:00 UTC" 
"2009-06-30 17:00:00 UTC" 
"2009-06-30 18:00:00 UTC"
"2009-06-30 19:00:00 UTC" 
"2009-07-01 08:00:00 UTC" 
"2009-07-01 09:00:00 UTC"
"2009-07-01 10:00:00 UTC" 
"2009-07-01 16:00:00 UTC" 
"2009-07-01 17:00:00 UTC"
"2009-07-01 18:00:00 UTC" 
"2009-07-01 19:00:00 UTC" 
"2009-07-02 08:00:00 UTC"
"2009-07-02 09:00:00 UTC" 
"2009-07-02 10:00:00 UTC" 
"2009-07-02 16:00:00 UTC"
"2009-07-02 17:00:00 UTC" 
"2009-07-02 18:00:00 UTC" 
"2009-07-02 19:00:00 UTC"
"2009-07-04 10:00:00 UTC" 
"2009-07-04 16:00:00 UTC" 
"2009-07-04 17:00:00 UTC"
"2010-06-22 16:00:00 UTC" 
"2010-06-22 17:00:00 UTC" 
"2010-06-22 18:00:00 UTC"
"2010-08-20 16:00:00 UTC" 
"2011-06-02 16:00:00 UTC" 
"2011-06-02 17:00:00 UTC"
"2011-06-02 18:00:00 UTC" 
"2011-06-03 10:00:00 UTC" 
"2011-06-03 16:00:00 UTC"
"2011-06-03 17:00:00 UTC" 
"2011-06-03 18:00:00 UTC" 
"2011-06-03 19:00:00 UTC"
```

Comment: Thanks guys both solutions were really nice but I prefer the base commands that's why I voted for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you'll want to convert your character strings to dates. Once you've done this, you can easily use `difftime()` to calculate time distances.

There are a number of packages that help you with this and even more ways to do so. So in addition to the answer provided using the `lubridate` package, here is a way to solve it in base `R`:

```
# (I'll assume your data is saved in a vector called my_dates)
my_dates <- gsub(" UTC", "", my_dates)   # removes " UTC" from all your dates (for no reason, see edit below)
my_dates <- as.POSIXlt(df$date)          # converts to date format
difftime(time1 = my_dates, time2 = my_dates[1], units = "sec")
Time differences in secs
# [1]         0  2419200  2422800  2505600  2509200  2512800  2516400  2563200  2566800  2570400  2592000  2595600
# [13]  2599200  2602800  2649600  2653200  2656800  2678400  2682000  2685600  2689200  2829600  2851200  2854800
# [25] 33350400 33354000 33357600 38448000 63158400 63162000 63165600 63223200 63244800 63248400 63252000 63255600
```

**Note:** In my initial answer, I used `as.Date.character()`, but this ignored the times after the dates! `as.Date()` also ignores the time and only focuses on the dates. `POSIXlt()` does the job and keeps both the times *and* the dates.

**Edit from comment:** Apparently `difftime()` is clever enough to recognise strings as dates and automatically gets the right format for the dates, too!:

```
difftime(my_dates, my_dates[1], units = "secs") 
# Time differences in secs
#  [1]        0  2419200  2422800  2505600  2509200  2512800  2516400  2563200  # 2566800  2570400  2592000  2595600
# [13]  2599200  2602800  2649600  2653200  2656800  2678400  2682000  2685600  2689200  2829600  2851200  2854800
# [25] 33350400 33354000 33357600 38448000 63158400 63162000 63165600 63223200 63244800 63248400 63252000 63255600
```

Comment: `difftime()` is the right solution here, but there's no need to fuss with the dates so much -  as simple `as.Date(my_dates)` works for me. In fact, you can even use `difftime()` directly on the character vector, because it's in the datetime format R expects.

Comment: Usually date formats look easy and turn out to be a hassle, instead of the other way around. +1 for `difftime` and Matt!

Answer (score 1):

The `lubridate` package is your friend in this scenario:

```
library(lubridate)
d <- read.table(text='"2009-06-01 16:00:00 UTC" 
                "2009-06-29 16:00:00 UTC" 
                "2009-06-29 17:00:00 UTC"
                "2009-06-30 16:00:00 UTC" 
                "2009-06-30 17:00:00 UTC" 
                "2009-06-30 18:00:00 UTC"
                "2009-06-30 19:00:00 UTC" 
                "2009-07-01 08:00:00 UTC" 
                "2009-07-01 09:00:00 UTC"
                "2009-07-01 10:00:00 UTC" 
                "2009-07-01 16:00:00 UTC" 
                "2009-07-01 17:00:00 UTC"
                "2009-07-01 18:00:00 UTC" 
                "2009-07-01 19:00:00 UTC" 
                "2009-07-02 08:00:00 UTC"
                "2009-07-02 09:00:00 UTC" 
                "2009-07-02 10:00:00 UTC" 
                "2009-07-02 16:00:00 UTC"
                "2009-07-02 17:00:00 UTC" 
                "2009-07-02 18:00:00 UTC" 
                "2009-07-02 19:00:00 UTC"
                "2009-07-04 10:00:00 UTC" 
                "2009-07-04 16:00:00 UTC" 
                "2009-07-04 17:00:00 UTC"
                "2010-06-22 16:00:00 UTC" 
                "2010-06-22 17:00:00 UTC" 
                "2010-06-22 18:00:00 UTC"
                "2010-08-20 16:00:00 UTC" 
                "2011-06-02 16:00:00 UTC" 
                "2011-06-02 17:00:00 UTC"
                "2011-06-02 18:00:00 UTC" 
                "2011-06-03 10:00:00 UTC" 
                "2011-06-03 16:00:00 UTC"
                "2011-06-03 17:00:00 UTC" 
                "2011-06-03 18:00:00 UTC" 
                "2011-06-03 19:00:00 UTC"', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

d <- ymd_hms(d[, 1])

sapply(d, function(x) x-d)
```

Comment: Since the output of this is a matrix, could you also demonstrate how you'd add that as a new column on a data.frame?